# mandrill merge tags not accepting variable value

Tags: javascript, mandrill

please excuse my first post! I am able to send "hardcoded" global_merge_vars successfully with

```
 `"autotext": "true",
  "merge": "true",
  "global_merge_vars": [
        {
            "vars": 
                {
                    "name": "LSMESSAGE",
                    "content": "hardcoded"
                }

        }
    ],

  "subject": "*|LSMESSAGE|*",
  "html": "<p> *|LSMESSAGE|* </p>"`
```

but am unable to pass a variable named ctlsm to the "content".

```
"autotext": "true",
  "merge": "true",
  "global_merge_vars": [
        {
            "vars": 
                {
                    "name": "LSMESSAGE",
                    "content": ctlsm
                }

        }
    ],

  "subject": "*|LSMESSAGE|*",
  "html": "<p> *|LSMESSAGE|* </p>"
```

I just get star*|LSMESSAGE|*star in my mail.
First question - is it possible to use a variable here? (I did try putting ctlsm in quotes: "ctlsm")
If yes, what am I doing wrong? The variable was declared before the mandrill post and has a value but seems to lose its value in the $ajax part.

```
// send email using mandrill and API key
      $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json",
data: { etc etc
```

Answer (score 0):

add + sign to concat string in javascript

```
"content": "+ctlsm+"
```

here is concat example for variable with string.

```
 var text = "hello" 
 document.write(text+" world"); /// this will write hello world
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could describe, *why* this solves the problem. (VLQRQ)

Comment: it is very simple . if you want to use variable in side any string in javascript then using + operator you can concat variable inside string

Answer (score 0):

thanks Nishit. It works now. Removed the "var" from the code, moved the "subject" and "html" code up to the top, and added "merge_language": "mailchimp" which I found in a  code snippet on the mandril site. Variable name ctlsm worked without quotes. Anyway, this did the trick. Here's the code that works:

```
// send email using mandrill and API key$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json",
data: {
"key": "yourapikeyhere",
"message": {
 "subject": "*|LSMESSAGE|*",
 "html": "<p>  *|LSMESSAGE|* </p>",
 "text": " *|LSMESSAGE|*",
 "from_email": "youremailhere",
  "to": [
      {
        "email": "youremailhere",
        "name": "yournamehere",
        "type": "to"
      },
      {
        "email": "youremailhere",
        "name": "yournamehere",
        "type": "to"
      }
    ],

  "autotext": "true",
  "merge": "true",
  "merge_language": "mailchimp",
  "global_merge_vars": [
        {
           "name": "LSMESSAGE",
            "content": ctlsm

        }
    ]



}
```

}